# Remove landforms from google maps with api react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, google-maps

is there a way to remove the reliefs/landforms from google maps knowing that i'm using api react-google-maps? This is what I tried :

```js
import { GoogleMap,withGoogleMap,withScriptjs,InfoWindow,Marker,GroundOverlay } from 'react-google-maps';

const GoogleMapsWrapper = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(props => {
  return <GoogleMap 
        {...props} 
        ref={props.onMapMounted}
        defaultOptions={defaultOptions}>
        >
        <GroundOverlay
      defaultUrl="https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg"
      defaultOpacity={.5}
        />
          {props.children}
      
      </GoogleMap>
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try some option:

```
streetViewControl: false,
fullscreenControl: false,
scaleControl: false,
mapTypeControl: false,
panControl: false,
zoomControl: false,
rotateControl: false
```